# Iterative approach to PageRank - confused on notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm new to the idea and terminology of Markov chains, but I want to make sure I understand how the iterations work.

From [this](https://youtu.be/TxOOhaDVq60?t=19m47s) video, he writes:

$$\vec{\pi}^T\vec{H} = \vec{\pi}^T$$

Where $\vec{\pi}$ is the initial vector and $\vec{H}$ is the link matrix.

I'm trying to understand what's written above - it's not saying that the two are actually equal to each other, right? That the right side is equal to the left? Because that would mean $\vec{H}$ does essentially nothing. Is it the programmatic approach where the right side is "set" to be the left side and this is applied iteratively?

Comment: No, the equation as written means that both sides are literally equal. This doesn't necessarily mean that $H$ does nothing, it means that we want to find a vector $\pi$ which $H$ keeps fixed. For example, suppose $H=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&\frac12\end{bmatrix}$. Then $\pi$ could be $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ but not $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @Rahul, thanks for your answer - but then where does the iterative component come in? How is he not defining iterations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$\pi$ vector tranpose times $H$ matrix will give me the new $\pi$." according to the video.

He is defining iterations: $$\pi^T_{(i+1)} =\pi^T_{(i)}H$$

and if you repeat this long enough, $\pi_{(i)} \rightarrow \pi^*$ where $\pi^*$ is a vector which satisfies

$$\pi^{*T}={\pi^{*T}}H$$

which is what he intends to obtain.

Here $\pi^*$ is known as the left eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue $1$ and this context, it is also known as the page rank.

While it does nothing to those eigenvectors with corresponding eigenvalue $1$, it does change when the vectors being multiplied to it is not one of those eigenvectors.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! Thanks so much! So the reason why $\pi^*$ has an eigenvalue of 1 is because it does not change when multiplied by $\vec{H}$? In other words, it scales itself by 1? And also by the same logic, $\vec{\pi}$ (in its initial state) does not have an eigenvalue of 1?

Comment: yup, that is the definition of a left eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue $1$. If at the beginning, the initial state has eigenvalue of $1$, your algorithm stop in a single step. You have reached your goal.

Answer (score 0):

A linear transformation can leaves lines fixed without being the identity. Consider a reflection in the $x$-axis: it leaves every vector along this axis unchanged, but obviously does something to every other vector in $\mathbb R^2$. This is a fundamental idea that underlies the concept of eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

The equation states only that $\pi$ is a *fixed point* of $H$. More specifically, that it’s a left eigenvector of $1$.